# Running Eclipse JVM arguments through a windows desktop shortcut

Tags: windows, eclipse, jvm

I want to run Eclipse through a desktop shortcut on windows with the -Duser.timezone argument you can use on the command line.

My shortcut target looks like this:

```
C:\Alan\SDK\3.7.1\eclipse.exe -vm "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw.exe" -vmargs -Xmx512m -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

As you can see I have increased memory space with the -X.. arguments. For whatever reason though I can't type -Duser.timezone=Europe/Dublin after the -vmargs entry. Is it not possible to do this through a shortcut? I can use this -D argument from the command line no problem.

edit: I would add it to the .ini file but that I am not allowed!

Comment: how would you add it to an ini file ? I have no such restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add your program arguments **before the VM arguments switch**. From the [vmargs documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm):

> All arguments following (but not including) the -vmargs entry are passed directly through to the indicated Java VM as virtual machine arguments.